# File Dialog error access VBA

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010, openfiledialog

I am trying to have the file dialog box pop up so the user can select a file path to export a file in VBA but for some reason it throws this error on the following line of code.

Error: Method 'FileDialog' of object '_Application' failed

Code: `longResult = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker).Show`

All Code:

```
If choice = 6 Then

Dim intResult As Long
Dim strPath As String
'the dialog is displayed to the user
longResult = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker).Show
'checks if user has cancled the dialog
If intResult <> 0 Then
    'dispaly message box
Call MsgBox(Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker _
    ).SelectedItems(1), vbInformation, "Selected Folder")
End If

Else

End

End If
```

I am really unsure how to fix this issue. I checked my syntax and everything.

Answer (score 6):

I know that this is a bit of an old question at this point, but since it doesn't actually have the answer, and I needed one today, I'm going to chime in with what I found just in case anyone else needs the answer too.

To fix this you need to add a reference to "Microsoft Office [yourversion] Object Library" in *Visual Basic Editor >> Tools >> References...*

The dialog in question should look like this:

[image: VBA References Dialog]

Answer (score 3):

Was trying to do the same thing myself and found this question. I realize that it is over a year old.

Try using the actual number (4) instead of msoFileDialogFolderPicker, that worked for me. I think something needs to be installed for the msoFileDialog constants to be initialized, when I tried printing any of the constants defined in the help file in the immediate window nothing was printed.

Also, why does your code have one variable longResult and one variable intResult?

Answer (score 0):

Almost nothing is an integer in VB6 as integer is a VB4 16 bit type. Win32 Integers are called Long in VB6/VBA.

This was to make porting 16 bit code to 32 bit easy.

Comment: I changed that but it still failed on that same line.

Answer (score 0):

Check out http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff865217%28v=office.15%29.aspx for more information on proper syntax with FileDialogue.Show method.  It appears you need a `Set` in front of your variable.

Comment: I tried to define as a `FileDialog` object but it is saying it does not exist.

Answer (score 0):

If you are after some cool UI, you can checkout my [Github](https://github.com/krishKM/VBA_TOOLS/blob/master/README.md#drag-and-drop-openfiledialog) for sample database using .NET wrapper dll. Which allows you to simply call a function and to open filedialog with **file-drag-and-drop** function

```
Dim FilePaths As String
    FilePaths = gDll.DLL.ShowDialogForFile("No multiple files allowed", False)
'Will return a JSONArray string.
'Multiple files can be opend by setting AllowMulti:=true
```

here what it looks like;

[image: In Action]