# is there a workaround for xFiledlg As FileDialog not working?

Tags: excel, vba

I found this code online. It's suppose to extract a excel sheet to PDF and insert it as attachment in Outlook, but i'm having error at the second line of the code.

```
Dim xFileDlg As FileDialog
```

Here is the link were I found this information : https://www.extendoffice.com/documents/excel/4412-excel-save-as-pdf-and-email.html

Thank you in advance for helping out. It's appreciated.

here it is :

```
Sub Saveaspdfandsend()
Dim xSht As Worksheet
Dim xFileDlg As FileDialog
Dim xFolder As String
Dim xYesorNo As Integer
Dim xOutlookObj As Object
Dim xEmailObj As Object
Dim xUsedRng As Range
 
Set xSht = ActiveSheet
Set xFileDlg = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
 
If xFileDlg.Show = True Then
   xFolder = xFileDlg.SelectedItems(1)
Else
   MsgBox "You must specify a folder to save the PDF into." & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & "Press OK to exit this macro.", vbCritical, "Must Specify Destination Folder"
   Exit Sub
End If
xFolder = xFolder + "\" + xSht.Name + ".pdf"
 
'Check if file already exist
If Len(Dir(xFolder)) > 0 Then
    xYesorNo = MsgBox(xFolder & " already exists." & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & "Do you want to overwrite it?", _
                      vbYesNo + vbQuestion, "File Exists")
    On Error Resume Next
    If xYesorNo = vbYes Then
        Kill xFolder
    Else
        MsgBox "if you don't overwrite the existing PDF, I can't continue." _
                    & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & "Press OK to exit this macro.", vbCritical, "Exiting Macro"
        Exit Sub
    End If
    If Err.Number <> 0 Then
        MsgBox "Unable to delete existing file.  Please make sure the file is not open or write protected." _
                    & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & "Press OK to exit this macro.", vbCritical, "Unable to Delete File"
        Exit Sub
    End If
End If
 
Set xUsedRng = xSht.UsedRange
If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(xUsedRng.Cells) <> 0 Then
    'Save as PDF file
    xSht.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, Filename:=xFolder, Quality:=xlQualityStandard
     
    'Create Outlook email
    Set xOutlookObj = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set xEmailObj = xOutlookObj.CreateItem(0)
    With xEmailObj
        .Display
        .CC = ""
        .Subject = xSht.Name + ".pdf"
        .Attachments.Add xFolder
        If DisplayEmail = False Then
            '.Send
        End If
    End With
Else
  MsgBox "The active worksheet cannot be blank"
  Exit Sub
End If
End Sub
```

[Link of problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RlkUP.png)

Comment: Is there any traceback or informationg regarding your error you could share too?

Comment: @IvanLibedinsky Compilation error, type not defined by user. (I tried to translate it, my Excel is in french).

Answer (score 0):

FileDialog works fine, most likely the problem is here:

```
If DisplayEmail = False Then
    '.Send
End If
```

DisplayEmail neither declared as variable nor is a method of MailItem object.

And I can't get the meaning of this If statement - as it might be assumed this section is to check whether the MailItem is displayed and sends it if not (displayed), but the item is displayed 5 lines before.

If you don't need the email to be sent without your review - remove this part of code and try again.

**Update**

As appeared, most likely a reference to Microsoft Office [version] Object Library is not set in *Visual Basic Editor >> Tools >> References* menu.

Comment: @Codingnoob try to replace `Dim xFileDlg As FileDialog` with `Dim xFileDlg As Object`. If the problem remain - add a screenshot of error to your main post.

Comment: It's still not working, I linked the image in main post. Thanks again so much.

Comment: @Codingnoob check answers with 3 votes from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27385079/file-dialog-error-access-vba)